# Choosing Symbols in an efficient way, in Arithmetic Code Algorithm, C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, compression

I'm trying to implement Arithmetic Code Algorithm to compress binary images (JPG images transformed to binary base using opencv). The problem is that I've to save in the compressed file, the encoded string and the symbols which I used to generate this encoded string and also their frequencies, so I can be able to decode it. The symbols take a lot of space even if I'm transforming them to ascii and if I tried to take less number of characters for each symbol the size of the encoded string becomes bigger. So I wonder if there's an efficient way to save symbols in the compressed file with minimum possible size. And I want to know the most efficient way to choose the symbols from the original file.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is "a lot of space" for you? Can you give an example i.e.: the size of an image before compression, the size of an image after compression, the sizeof symbols, the size of frequencies?

Comment: What is a symbol for you? How many bits does it have?

Comment: I've 325,592,005 bytes of binary images, when I'm trying to compress them taking 64bit size for each symbol, which in binary base and encode, then transform the encoded string and the symbols to ascii. The size of encoded string is 2.8MB and the size of the symbols itself 6.1MB

Comment: 325,592,005 bytes is 310 megabytes. You managed to compress this image into 2.8+6.1=8.9 megabytes so you decreased the size by 97%. It's a good result and I wouldn't worry here.

Comment: Besides 6.1 megabytes of 64 bits long symbols means that you have around 800K of them. It is much less than the maximum possible number of possible symbols i.e. 2^64 - 1. It is again a good result.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for helping ^_^. But I've a last question. If I tried to compress the image by several algorithms is this will help to decrease the size? I mean by applying run length algorithm then huffman then arithmetic code this will result less size or all of this is in vain?

Comment: I added the full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

325,592,005 bytes is 310 megabytes. You managed to compress this image into 2.8+6.1=8.9 megabytes so you decreased the size by 97%. It's a good result and I wouldn't worry here. Besides 6.1 megabytes of 64 bits long symbols means that you have around 800K of them. It is much less than the maximum possible number of possible symbols i.e. 2^64 - 1. It is again a good result.

As to your question about using multiple compression algorithms. Firstly, you have to know that in the case of the loosless compression the optimal number of bits per symbol is equal to the entropy. And the arithmetic encoding is close to be optimal (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression), [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding) or [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/68252/arithmetic-coding-and-the-optimal-compression-ratio)). It means that there is no much sense in using more than 1 algorithm one after another, if one of them is the arithmetic encoding.

As to the arithmetic coding vs Huffman codes. The latter is actually the special case of the former. And as far as I know the arithmetic encoding is always at least as good as Huffman codes.

It is also worth adding one thing. If you can consider lossy compression there is actually no limit in the compression rate. Or in other words, you can compress data as much as you want as long as quality loss is still acceptable for you. However, even in this case using multiple compression algorithms is not required. The one is enough.